# Python rounding principle

Tags: python

I'm asking you if there's anything I don't know because Python round function is weird.
I thought the round function was rounding up

```
enter code here
print(round(51.5))
print(round(54.5))
```

Outputs at 52 54 each.
If you round up from 54.5, shouldn't it be 55?
Question 2. I want to know why it says 54.
Question3. I want to round up properly, so I would appreciate it if you could tell me how to do it without any errors.

Comment: that is in the floating point standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#Rounding_rules

Comment: See the docs: "if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done toward the even choice (so, for example, both round(0.5) and round(-0.5) are 0, and round(1.5) is 2)"

Comment: For rounding up use [`math.ceil`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.ceil)

Comment: Please take note that "round up properly" is not well-defined. There are several rounding schemes, even for "round up". What result do you expect for ``magic_round(54.4)`` and ``magic_round(-54.5)``? Python's ``round`` uses [round half to even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) – does any of the other rounding schemes in the linked article do what you want?

Comment: It's all described in the [`round()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) docs. Did you look there and didn't understand something specific?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate the error but the round function was working fine. It is rounding 5.5 to 6.

If you want to round up you can use the math.ceil method.

If you want to round down you can use the math.floor method.

Note - to use math.ceil and math.floor only after importing the math package.

Comment: Can you clarify in how far you were not able to replicate the issue? Yes, 5.5 is rounded up to 6, "but" 4.5 is rounded down to 4. There is a reason why all numbers in the question have an even integer parts.